# Polymer WebComponents and Firefox compatibility

Tags: firefox, polymer

My web component is

```
<dom-module id="my-component">
    <template>
        <h2>YES, IT IS!</h2>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'my-component',
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

and my HTML page is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="webjars/webcomponentsjs/0.7.22/webcomponents.js"></script>
        <link rel="import" href="webjars/polymer-elements-all/0.1.0/polymer/polymer.html">
        <link rel="import" href="my-component.html">    
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Is this web component shown?</h1>
        <my-component></my-component>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am importing the Polyfills and Polymer, it is OK for Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge, even for Internet Explorer, however it is not OK for Firefox. In Firefox my component is not getting attached.

I have also enabled these two preferences https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components.

Please help :)

Comment: Apart from the Polyfills webjar, I've also tried with the `webcomponentsjs-0.7.22` CDN library: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/0.7.22/webcomponents.js

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to move the following line from your "HTML page" to your "web component"? (Make sure the url is correct.)

```
<link rel="import" href="webjars/polymer-elements-all/0.1.0/polymer/polymer.html">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Still the same. I even tried using the `bower_components` and importing 
  `<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">`

The paths are correct, I made sure.